# Can this seeming ambiguity be parsed in a LALR(1) parser (PLY)?

Tags: parsing, yacc, ply, lalr

I have a large-ish grammar in PLY (Python Lexx Yacc) for a language that has some particular challenges in parsing.  The language allows the leading syntax of two kinds of calls to look the same almost until the end of the call non-terminal.  This provides lot's of opportunity for reduce/reduce conflicts, since the semantics of tokens along the way are different, but can be built out of the same terminal tokens.  I've extracted simple before/after versions of the grammar below, which I'll explain a bit.

Originally, expressions were a typical "Stratified Grammar," taking calls and literals and such to primary, then primary through unary, then binary to general expression. The problem was that `Call_expr` with two arguments conflicts with the version of `Iter_expr` that begins with two Id's before the '/'.  The conflict was on the comma after the first argument in the call, since originally, `Expr -> ... -> Primary_expr -> Name_expr -> Id` was allowed.  The parser could either reduce `Id` to `Expr` to match the `Call_expr`, or leave it to match the `Iter_expr`.  Looking ahead to the comma didn't help it decide. If the first argument to a call is just an identifier (like a variable), this is legitimate ambiguity.  Consider input `id > id ( id , id ...` .

My approach was to make a kind of expression that could **not** be just an `Id`.  I added the production chain through all the expressions to give them '`_nn`' versions--'not a name.'  I could then define productions for `Call_expr` that use any syntax in the first argument that make it more than just a name (e.g. operators, calls, etc.) to reduce it to `BinOp_expr_nn`, and *also* allow a call production that just has an `Id` as the first argument.  This should convince the parser to just shift until it could resolve either the `Iter_expr` or the `Call_expr` (or at least know which path it's on.)

As you might have guessed, this screws everything up :).  Tinkering with the expression chain also tinkers with `Primary_expr`, which I still need to allow to reduce to `Id`.  But now, that's a reduce/reduce conflict--every `Primary_expr` can stay there or go on to `Unary_expr`.  I can order those to make a choice (which might work), but I expect I'll just end up chasing another and another.

So, my question is:  Is there a technique someone can articulate about how to allow the same tokens represent different semantics (i.e. expr vs id) that can still be parsed with LALR(1) like PLY?  Short of that, any useful hacks that help manage the problem?  Can this be disambiguated?

```
terminals:  '+' '^' ',' '>' '(' ')' '/' ':' 'id' 'literal' 
   (i.e. punctuation (besides '->' and '|', initial-lower-case words)
non-terminals:  initial-Upper-case words
```

Original Grammar:

```
S'-> S
S -> Call_expr
   | Iter_expr
Expr -> BinOp_expr
BinOp_expr -> Unary_expr
BinOp_expr -> BinOp_expr '+' BinOp_expr
Unary_expr -> Primary_expr
   | '^' BinOp_expr
Primary_expr -> Name_expr
   | Call_expr
   | Iter_expr
   | Literal_expr
Name_expr -> Id
Args -> Expr
   | Args ',' Expr
Call_expr -> Primary_expr '>' Id '(' ')'
   | Primary_expr '>' Id '(' Args ')'
Iter_expr -> Primary_expr '>' Id '(' Id '/' Expr ')'
   | Primary_expr '>' Id '(' Id ':' Id '/' Expr ')'
   | Primary_expr '>' Id '(' Id ',' Id ':' Id '/' Expr ')'
Literal_expr -> literal
Id -> id
```

My attempt to disambiguate the first argument in `Call_expr`:

```
S'-> S
S -> Call_expr
   | Iter_expr
Expr -> BinOp_expr_nn
   | BinOp_expr
BinOp_expr -> BinOp_expr_nn
   | Unary_expr
BinOp_expr_nn -> Unary_expr_nn
   | BinOp_expr '+' BinOp_expr
Unary_expr -> Primary_expr
   | Unary_expr_nn
Unary_expr_nn -> Primary_expr_nn
   | '^' BinOp_expr
Primary_expr -> Primary_expr_nn
   | Name_expr
Primary_expr_nn -> Call_expr
   | Iter_expr
   | Literal_expr
Name_expr -> Id
Args -> Expr
   | Args ',' Expr
Call_expr -> Primary_expr '>' Id '(' ')'
   | Primary_expr '>' Id '(' Expr ')'
   | Primary_expr '>' Id '(' Id , Args ')'
   | Primary_expr '>' Id '(' BinOp_expr_nn , Args ')'
Iter_expr -> Primary_expr '>' Id '(' Id '/' Expr ')'
   | Primary_expr '>' Id '(' Id ':' Id '/' Expr ')'
   | Primary_expr '>' Id '(' Id ',' Id ':' Id '/' Expr ')'
Literal_expr -> literal
Id -> id
```

Comment: I'd just fold together Iter_Expr and Call_Expr into one syntax, and then sort out what it is by walking the AST.  If you know any Lisp, it should be obvious.  So that is to say, allow those Id : Id / Expr forms in the Call_Expr syntax. Then walk the Call_Expr nodes to determine whether they are actually valid Iter_exprs.  This will over-generate: allow invalid uses of Id : Id / Expr; you can check for that and diagnose.

Comment: @rici:  Sorry for the errors, but you've interpreted most correctly.  '>' _should_ be in the list of terminals; it separates some kinds of calls from others which are not included in my toy version. All of these calls can be chained ala "foo > bar(baz / a + baz) > qux(b, c, d, e)," and each lhs of '>' is a primary_expr.  '/' is another syntax separator, not an operator.  Sorry for the confusion: most of this comes from simplifications, and out of context, I'm sure it seems really weird.

Comment: I still think you want `BinOp_expr -> Unary_expr | BinOp_expr '+' Unary_expr` (so that `+` is less-associative; as written, it is ambiguous) and `Unary_expr -> Primary_expr | '^' Unary_expr` so that `^ a + b` means `(^a) + b` rather than `^(a + b)`). (Or possibly  `Unary_expr -> Primary_expr | '^' Primary_expr`, if `^^a` is not to be allowed.)

Comment: You might also want `Primary_expr -> '(' Expr ')'` in order to allow parenthesization.

Comment: Yes, I'm considering those.  At the moment, I'm using precedence to resolve all that, but will play around with the disambiguation.  Thanks to you and @Kaz for your wonderful suggestions.  Much Appreciated, and I should be on my way now!

Comment: @jspencer: precedence declarations will resolve the issue with the binary operator(s), but not the unary operator issue (if you have separated out Unary_expr as in your example).

Comment: @jspencer: Also, I added an LALR(1) grammar without conflicts, which I think produces the correct language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite the title of your post, your grammar is not ambiguous. It is simply not LR(1), for the reason you mention: the input

```
A ( B ,
```

can be the start of either a `Call_expr` or an `Iter_expr`. In the first case, the `B` must be reduced to an `Expr` and then to `Args`; in the second case, it must not be reduced because it needs to still be an `id` when the right-hand side `id '(' id ',' id ':' id '/' Expr ')'` is reduced. The decision cannot be made simply by looking at a single lookahead token (the <kbd>,</kbd>), so there is a shift-reduce conflict.

This conflict can be resolved with at most two additional lookahead tokens, since the shift is only a valid action if the <kbd>,</kbd> is followed by precisely an `id` and then a <kbd>:</kbd>. So that makes the grammar LALR(3). Unfortunately, Ply does not generate LALR(3) parsers (and neither does yacc/bison), but there are some alternatives.

#### 1. Use a different parsing algorithm

Since the grammar is unambiguous, it can be parsed without problems (and without any modifications) with a GLR parser. Ply doesn't produce GLR parsers either, but Bison can. That's not likely to be of much use to you, but I thought I should mention it in case you are not locked into the use of Python.

#### 2. Use a grammar which allows some invalid inputs, and discard them with semantic analysis

This is almost certainly the simplest solution, and it's what I would normally recommend. If you change the definition of `Iter_expr` to:

```
Iter_expr : id '(' id '/' Expr ')'
          | id '(' Args ':' id '/' Expr ')'
```

then it will still recognize every valid input (since both `id` and `id , id` are valid instances of `Args`). This removes the shift-reduce conflict; in effect, it lets the parser avoid having to make a decision until it either encounters a <kbd>)</kbd> (which would indicate a `Call_expr`) or a <kbd>:</kbd> (indicating a `Iter_expr`). (There's no problem with the first alternative for `Iter_expr` since the decision to shift the <kbd>/</kbd> instead of reducing `id` does not require additional lookahead.)

Of course, the second production for `Iter_expr` will recognize a lot of things which are not valid iteration expressions: lists of more than 2 items, and lists which include expressions more complicated than just a single `id`. However, those inputs are not valid programs at all, so they can simply be rejected in the action for `Iter_expr`. The precise code to recognize a valid iteration will depend on how you represent your AST but it's not complicated: just check to make sure that the length of the `Args` is either one or two, and that each item in the list is just an `id`.

#### 3. Use a lexical hack

One way to compensate for the lack of lookahead information is to collect it in the lexer by collecting the necessary lookahead into a buffer and only output lexemes when their syntactic category is known. In this case, the lexer can look for the sequence `'(' id ',' id ':'` and mark the first `id` so that it can only be used in an `Iter_expr`. In this case, the only change to the grammar is:

```
Iter_expr : id '(' id '/' Expr ')'
          | id '(' id ':' id '/' Expr ')'
          | id '(' iter_id ',' id ':' id '/' Expr ')'
```

While this will work fine in this particular case, it is not very maintainable. In particular, it relies on being able to define a simple and unambiguous pattern which can be implemented in the lexer. Since that pattern is a simplification of the grammar, it is quite possible that some future syntactic addition will create a syntax which also matches the same pattern. (This is called the lexical "hack" for a reason.)

#### 4. Find an LALR(1) grammar

As indicated, this grammar is `LALR(3)`. But there is no such thing as an `LALR(3)` *language*. Or more precisely, if a language has an `LALR(k)` grammar, then it also has an `LALR(1)` grammar, and that grammar can be produced mechanically from the `LALR(k)` grammar. Moreover, given a parse for the one-symbol lookahead grammar, it is possible to reconstruct the parse tree for the original grammar.

Because the mechanically-produced grammars are quite large, this procedure is not very attractive, and I don't know of an implementation of the algorithm. Instead, it is most common to attempt to rewrite just a part of the grammar, as you attempted in the original question. This can be done, certainly, but the end result is not totally intuitive.

However, it's not that difficult. Here, for example, is a slightly simplified version of your grammar, with the redundant unit productions removed and a couple of fixes in operator precedence (possibly incorrect, since I don't know what semantics you're aiming for).

The productions whose names end with `N` do not produce `ID`. For each of them, there is a corresponding production without the `N` which adds `ID`. Once that is done, it was necessary to rewrite `Args` to use the `ExprN` production, as well as allowing the various argument lists which start with one or two `ID`s. The `Chain` production was just to avoid some repetition.

```
Start   : Call
        | Iter
Expr    : ID
        | ExprN
ExprN   : UnaryN
        | Expr '+' Unary
Unary   : ID
        | UnaryN
UnaryN  : ChainN
        | '^' Chain
Chain   : ID
        | ChainN
ChainN  : PrimaryN
        | Chain '>' CallIter
PrimaryN: LITERAL
        | Call
        | Iter
        | '(' Expr ')'
Call    : ID '(' ')'
        | ID '(' ID ')'
        | ID '(' ID ',' ID ')'
        | ID '(' Args ')'
Iter    : ID '(' ID '/' Expr ')'
        | ID '(' ID ':' ID '/' Expr ')'
        | ID '(' ID ',' ID ':' ID '/' Expr ')'
Args    : ExprN ExprList
        | ID ',' ExprN ExprList
        | ID ',' ID ',' Expr ExprList
ExprList:
        | ExprList ',' Expr
```

I haven't tested this as much as I would have wanted to, but I think it produces the correct language.

Comment: Thanks for such thoroughness.  I like the idea of a more explicit grammar, but it _does_ lead to many reduce/reduce conflicts, requiring carefully ordered rules.  I'm not even sure I can get it all to work (consider "a + b + c", parsed to "Expr '+' UnaryN . '+' 'c'".  If we apply ExprN -> UnaryN, we shift in and perform "b+c" to become ExprN. Now, there's no way to reduce Expr '+' Unary).  Given the complexity in the grammar and the need to order and tweak so carefully, do you feel that it is better to go this route, or just open up the grammar and handle things by examining the AST/semantics?

Comment: @jspencer: I put the solutions in rough order of attractiveness and said explicitly in the second option that it's the one I'd recommend (unless you can use a GLR generator).

Comment: @jspencer: I did, however, test the grammar I provided. It parses `x(a+b+c)` as `('Call', ['x', '(', ('Args', [('ExprN', [('ExprN', ['a', '+', 'b']), '+', 'c'])]), ')'])` which is correct, assuming that your `+` operator is left-associative. (Note: the syntax tree constructor I used doesn't show unit reductions.)

Comment: Maybe a better example is "a + b > c() + d" (which should be "a + (b > c()) + d."  I probably have other complications due to the full grammar, but I run into a lot of these cases where either choice is right in different cases.  I still don't have a firm grasp on how to prevent these from being conflicts and instead force the parser down the (always) correct path.  At least, not in a full-scale grammar (~160 rules).  More struggle! :)

Comment: @jspencer: That one works fine, too. I parsed `x(a+b>c()+d)` (because your grammar requires a call or iter as the top-level form), and the resulting parse was effectively `x((a+(b>c()))+d)`. What makes you think it would be wrong? My Ply program is trivial; it's mostly the grammar I already pasted. But if you really can't reproduce it, I could put it up somewhere.

Comment: You're very kind.  I'm sure your test is correct.  In my _full_ grammar, there are more complications (which I haven't posted nor fully understood!) that are no doubt the issue.  The symptom I keep getting seems to come from the ability to use `Chain -> ChainN` and `UnaryN -> ChainN', or other such choices.  In some contexts, I want one, in others, the other.  For instance, my literals can include Expr.  I'm still struggling to intuitively understand how to constrain things so there's only one choice.  But I think I have to just wrestle with it until it becomes clear.  General advice welcome!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170190/discussion-between-jspencer-and-rici).